# Why is ImportXML not working for a specific field while trying to scrape kickstarter.com?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to screen scrape funding status of a specific Kickstarter project.
I am using following formula in my Google spreadsheet, what I am trying here is to get the $ amount of project's funding status:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1904431672/trsst-a-distributed-secure-blog-platform-for-the-o","//data[@class='Project942741362']")
```

It returns #N/A in the cell, with comment:

> error: The xPath query did not return any data.

When I try using ImportXML on other parts of the same webpage it seems to work perfectly well. Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444976/get-many-webpages-updation-alerts-systematic-automated-web-scraping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the tag "data" is not correctly parsed.

A choice of workaround may be:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("http://...", "//div[@id='pledged']"), "^\S*")
```