# Get many webpages updation alerts. Systematic automated web scraping

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, xml-parsing, data-modeling

I have used google sheet function IMPORTXML for scraping specific parts of webpages but It's not working properly with long xpath, not fluent, not smooth on tons of websites URL.
I have also tried distill extension, excel scraping from web table but It is also not long term smooth solution.
Please help to get notified on changes / updation of specific parts of tons of webpages.